# Boost ASIO - process data while still receiving

Tags: c++, boost, pipeline, asio

I am new to Boost ASIO and have the following use case:
A client sends 1 MB data to a server. The server is able to process each byte of the data independent from the remaining data. My current solution is using the read_some and write_some methods for the server and client, respectively. This works well, but I would like to speed up my implementation by letting the server directly process the data while it still receives them. I already had a look at the documented examples but could not find one that fits my requirements. 
I also wonder how I can take track how many bytes are received so far. I always have the same amount of data that the client sends.

Thank you in advance! Best regards.

Comment: Send the data in smaller chunks. What have you tried?

Comment: setting tcp_nodelay may also help?